# Best Place to check shared secret in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I Web Api is exposed through Azure Api Management portal and I have added a policy to SET HTTP header with a shared secret. This way i want to block access to my api backend (api hosted on azure web app). Now i am wondering where should i add the custom logic in my webapi to check that shared secret? Should it be actionFilters?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest place is with a Message Handler.  It should look something like this...

```
 public class RestrictClientHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> secrets = null;
            request.Headers.TryGetValues("myapi-secret",out secrets);
            var secret = secrets.FirstOrDefault();
            if (secret == null || secret != "the secret" )
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) { RequestMessage = request, Content=new StringContent("Direct access to this API is not allowed")});
            }
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

And you install this by adding it to the MessageHandlers collection that hangs off your config object.